# Tools available for debugging production Issues in Java applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, heap-dump

Just wondering what are various tools & techniques out there to debug production issues on Java applications. 
Like,

- What are the ways and tools to take thread dumps?
- What are the ways and tools to take heap dumps?
- What are the tools to analyse the above dumps?

(Assumption all are in Linux/Unix environment)

Comment: I edited your post, as I am fairly sure you were interested in memory _dumps_, not memory _dumbs_ ;-)

Comment: What is the difference between a memory dump and a heap dump for you?

Comment: Thank you guys, for pointing out all the typo's.. I have corrected my questions.

Comment: Consider adding the details of the JVM you are using to the question.  For Linux this might be Sun Java, OpenJDK, IBM Java, JRockit...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What are the ways and tools to take thread dumps?

For a thread dump, you can use JConsole, VisualVM or, more simply, send a QUIT signal to the target process

```
kill -QUIT <pid>
```

or

```
kill -3 <pid>
```

Since Java 5, there is also [`jstack`](http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/jstack) which is platform independent and has a nice `-m` option to print both Java and native frames (mixed mode).

> What are the ways and tools to take heap dumps?

With Sun VMs, `jmap`, Sun [JConsole](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jconsole.html), Sun [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/heapdump.html), SAP JVMMon. For IBM VMs, check [this page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer#System_Dumps_and_Heap_Dumps_from_IBM_Virtual_Machines). Actually, the Eclipse MAT wiki has a nice [Getting a Heap Dump](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer#Getting_a_Heap_Dump) section summarizing all the options.

> What are the tools to analyse the above dumps?

For thread dumps I use [TDA - Thread Dump Analyzer](https://tda.dev.java.net/) (for Sun JDKs) and [IBM Thread and Monitor Dump Analyzer](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/jca) (for IBM JDKs). [Samurai](http://yusuke.homeip.net/samurai/en/index.html) is also very nice (it works like a `tail -f` and picks up thread dumps from your std/stderr automatically, it can also read "-verbose:gc" logs) and has been tested against VMs from Apple, BEA, HP, Sun and IBM (can also read IBM's javacore).

For heap dumps, I use [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/heapdump.html) (for Sun JDKs) or [IBM Heap Dump Analyzer](http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/heapanalyzer) (only for IBM JDKs) or the über awesome [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) depending on my needs. The later is *able to work with HPROF binary heap dumps (produced by Sun, HP, SAP, etc... JVMs), IBM system dumps (after preprocessing them), and IBM portable heap dumps (PHD) from a variety of IBM platforms).*

Comment: Thanks! I will go through these links to get more info...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming JDK 6, Take a look at the following article to obtain thread dumps of a running program:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/

You can use JHat to do heap analysis:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html

If you want to do memory dumps take a look at jmap:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html

Alternatively, if you need to do some more in depth analysis look at a profiler such as Yourkit:

http://www.yourkit.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's also these two things that can interest you:

- [JConsole can dump the heap](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)
- [Ctrl-break to do a thread dump](http://www.adaptj.com/main/tracehowtos)

Comment: There is not Ctrl-break under Linux... it's kill -3 all the way...

Comment: He is anyway not interested in the thread dump :) That was just to complement your answer. But thanks for pointing me that out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard toolset for JVMs.  These are vendor dependant, and you should consult the documentation.

For Sun Java 6 the VisualVM program is very, very helpful to get a quick profile and stack trace of a running program.

Answer (score 1):

The tool I use for this kind of debugging a Sun JVM are

- [jstack](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html) to take a thread dump
- [jmap](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jmap.html) to take a memory/heap dump, or histogram
- [eclipse mat](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) for post analysis of the heap dump produced by jmap
- [visual vm](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) has a nice ui for live analysis of the vm (can also take heap and thread dumps)

Answer (score 0):

And I think the best way to debug java application in production environment is NOT dump and so on, but a good managment of **logs**.

See for instance [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Comment: Huh? Thread dumps and Heap dumps are incredibly valuable and and while logs are very useful too, they won't tell you what threads (including the one of the server) were doing or what was in memory when you got this OOM. You can't do serious problems analysis with logs only (especially if you mean application logs).

Comment: logs are primarily used for getting answers to questions you knew you would be asking later.  Now, what about those questions you did _not_ think of then?

Answer (score 0):

To debug issues with memory allocations, [InMemProfiler](http://wiki.github.com/mchr3k/org.inmemprofiler/) can be used at the command line. Live vs collected allocations can be tracked and collected objects can be split into buckets based on their lifetimes.

In trace mode this tool can be used to [identify the source of memory allocations](http://wiki.github.com/mchr3k/org.inmemprofiler/identifying-memory-allocators).